# help with access query

Tags: ms-access

i have this table Discount:

```
from | to | Dis
1    | 50 | 10
51   | 80 | 20
81   | 99 | 30
99   |120 | 40
```

and i have this work table MyTable:

```
id | sum | dis
123| 22  | 
222| 85  |
131| 85  |
```

how to fill the dis field in MyTable ? that the table will look like this:

(if the sum between the from and the to value)

```
id | sum | dis
123| 22  | 10
222| 85  | 30
131| 95  | 40
```

i need it in access

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to Update `MyTable`, Create it, or just create a query that produces those results?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an unequal join, most people thing that joins have to be where sometime equals something but that is not the case

```
SELECT tblMyTable.ID, tblMyTable.Sum, tblDiscount.Dis
FROM tblMyTable INNER JOIN tblDiscount ON tblMyTable.Sum <= tblDiscount.To AND tblMyTable.Sum >= tblDiscount.From
```

Access does not support viewing them in design mode so you have to write the SQL yourself

EDIT:
Here is a slighlty different version that is an outer join so if you have not setup a discount range for that value it will default to 0

```
SELECT tblMyTable.ID, tblMyTable.Sum, NZ(tblDiscount.Dis,0) AS Discount
FROM tblMyTable LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDiscount ON tblMyTable.Sum <= tblDiscount.To AND tblMyTable.Sum >= tblDiscount.From
```

Comment: Note, though, that you can build the query with equi-joins in Design view, then edit the SQL to set the other comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fairly standar solution, which is:

```
SELECT MyTable.id, MyTable.sum, Discount.Dis
FROM Discount, MyTable
WHERE MyTable.sum Between [Discount].[From] And [Discount].[To]
```

This can be set up in the query design window.

Comment: Would this query not have a problem if no discount range has been entered for a price? Just after posting my answer I did an edit so that if a discount range has not been entered it will default to 0

Comment: I am not sure I see it as a problem that no discount is returned where no discount exists.

Comment: Sorry I mean that if you had 5 items in your sales table and ran your query it might only return 4 items if the 5th item's price did not fall into a discount range

Comment: @Kevin Ross If the fifth item's price does not fall into the discount range, then it does not have a discount. From the above tables, it would seem that the information is intended to update MyTable. If the fifth item had a discount based on some other criteria, your query would overwrite that with zero. This might not be the desired result. It is not uncommon to update a main table with discount information when discounts may vary over time.

Comment: Furthermore, zero is not the same a null and to assume that the discount is zero when, I would argue, it is more properly null because the information has not been supplied, seems to be going to far.

Comment: I was reading the OP as a query to produce an invoice type report and in that case would it be wrong for an item not to be charged to the client just because no discount range had been set for the price of that line item? I guess it is over to the OP to tell us which is the desired outcome, do not show the item at all if no discount is entered (your query or my 1st query) or display the item but with a zero discount (my 2nd query)

Comment: @Kevin Ross The table `MyTable` shown in the question includes the fields `id | sum | dis` I think `dis` can be taken as discount. But yes, he or she has not specifically stated that an update query is required.